# How to run Elasticsearch completion suggester query on limited set of documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using a completion suggester in Elasticsearch on a single field. The type contains documents of several users. Is there a way to limit the returned suggestions to documents that match a specific query?

I'm currently using this query:

```
{
  "name" : {
    "text" : "Peter",
    "completion" : {
      "field" : "name_suggest"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to combine this query with a different one, e.g.

```
{
    "query":{
        "term" : {
            "user_id" : "590c5bd2819c3e225c990b48"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [context suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/suggester-context.html), which is just a specialized completion suggester with filtering capabilities - however this is still not a regular query filter, just keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify both the query and the suggester in your query, like this:

```
{
    "query":{
        "term" : {
            "user_id" : "590c5bd2819c3e225c990b48"
        }
    },
    "suggest": {
        "name" : {
            "text" : "Peter",
            "completion" : {
                "field" : "name_suggest"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This query also returns results with documents, that don't have a matching user_id field.

Comment: @Val do you know of any way to combine the query & the suggester? Has anything changed since 2017?

Comment: @Joe there hasn't been any groundbreaking changes since ES 5.0, but if you have a specific use case in mind, I suggest you create a new thread, so we can dig into it ;-)

Comment: :) It's basically the same question. Suggesters not respecting the `query`. But I suppose it's out of question as per https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/27513#issuecomment-346771916

Comment: @Joe Correct, the two are not correlated for obvious performance reasons (and also the fact that they both work off different and unrelated data structures). But the context suggester supports some basic "filtering"

Comment: Yea I hear that. But I got a single index for a bunch of clients and I have to filter b/c I ofc can't be suggesting items from other clients.

Comment: @Joe yes, and in that case, that's exactly what the context suggester would help you with

Comment: Even if i have a complex bool query? The docs seemed to only propose simple context filtering.

Comment: @Joe Of course, that filtering context is pretty basic, maybe you can encode the condition for each document into a new field that you can use in your context suggester

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar use case, and I've posted my question on elastic search forum, see [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/completion-suggester-limit-documents/92314)

From what I've read so far, I don't think with completion suggester you can limit documents. They essentially create a finite state transducer (prefix tree) at index time, this makes it fast but you lose the flexibility of filtering on additional fields. I don't think context suggester would work in your case (let me know if i am wrong), because the cardinality of user_id is very high.

I think edge-ngrams partial matching is more flexible and might actually work in your use case.

Let me know what you end up implementing.

Comment: I actually went with the context suggesters like @alr suggested. I'm building a service for a small amount of users, with many documents for each user, so a context suggester should work fine.